# Javascript delegate and numeric() function

Tags: javascript

My website has a lot of dynamic content on the DOM. How can I delegate the numeric() function?

I know I have to do something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('.js-numeric', 'keydown' (change etc.) function() {});
```

But I am not sure how to insert the `numeric()` function. If I want to use the numeric function for static content it works fine, like this:

```
$(".js-numeric").numeric();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your elements are in the `body` tag you could do this:

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', '.js-numeric', function() {})
```

You swapped the arguments around, if you [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can see that:

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

takes `events` *before* the `selector` instead of the other way around as you did at the moment.

If you read my code snippet above it *reads* more logical than the code you've written ( not that I write cleaner code but just that the jQuery developers think about these things :) )

This would delegate the `keydown` event from the `document.body` to any dynamically added `.js-numeric` element.

If you want to call `.numeric()` on the element which has been `keydown`ed then you would write it like this:

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', '.js-numeric', function() {
    // $(this) is the element that triggered the event
    $(this).numeric();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you had the syntax around the wrong way

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '.js-numeric', function( e ) {
  stackLog( e.which );
  $(this).numeric();
});

function stackLog( log ){
  var _console = document.querySelector('#console');
  _console.innerHTML = log + '\n' + _console.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="js-numeric"></textarea>
<pre id="console"></pre>
```